# How to install libxpm.so.6 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to install oracle dev suite on ubuntu 14.04, but it is erroring out saying 'Cant access the shared object libxpm.so.6'. What should i do to resolve this problem?